# Using Linq and XDocument, can I get all the child elements under parent tag?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML

```
<data>
  <summary>
    <account curr_desc='USD' acct_nbr='123' net='1000.00' />
    <account curr_desc='USD' acct_nbr='456' net='2000.00' />
  </summary>
  <details>
    <accounts>
      <account acct_nbr="123" curr="USD">
        <activity color='False' settle_date='02 Jul 2010' amt='580.00' />
        <activity color='True' settle_date='09 Jul 2010' amt='420.00' />
      </account>
      <account acct_nbr="456" curr="USD">
        <activity color='True' settle_date='12 Dec 2010' amt='1500.00' />
        <activity color='True' settle_date='19 Dec 2010' amt='500.00' />
      </account>
    </accounts>
  </details>
</data>
```

Using Linq and XDocument, I can extract "summary" information but how can I extract "account" information under "summary" tag?

```
XDocument XMLDoc = XDocument.Load("testdata.xml");
XElement accounts = (from xml2 in XMLDoc.Descendants("summary")
                    select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I specify something like "`summary/account`" so that it returns me all the elements under `<summary>`? Note, that I have `<account>` under `<detail><accounts>`, I only want the elements under summary tag.

Comment: you should check out LinqPad, it lets you test this kind of thing on the fly. its neat. :)

Comment: Writing `from x in … select x` is useless. Just write the code after `in` directly.

Comment: 2svick, you are right actually.. I didn't notice that. I have updated the code now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use the `Elements` method:

```
var accounts = doc.Root.Elements("summary").Elements("account");
```

Or, alternatively, `XPathSelectElements`, which in this case is simpler:

```
var accounts = doc.XPathSelectElements("/data/summary/account");
```

In this instance you can also use `Descendants`, as Andrew Barber suggested, but in general you should only do this when you really want to find all descendants with a given name, and not just immediate children.  Otherwise your code does a lot of searching that it doesn't need to, and may return elements you don't want it to.

Comment: Oh... I hadn't even realized he was using `Descendants` rather than `Elements`!!!

Comment: Fixed my answer, and +1 for noting that; `Descendants` would work in this case, but it could have bad results if there were other elements with the same names elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
var accountSummaryElems = 
   XMLDoc.Element("summary").Elements("account");
```

This gives you a collection of the `account` elements under the `summary` element. You can then iterate them to get the values.

EDITED to use the same pattern you were; I call `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` because that code won't run anyway if the "account" element is not found.

Then you have the right idea with iterating over the collection returned.

Comment: thanks Andrew. I guess I am able to use your solution to get the result. I am editing my original post. Appreciate if you can validate.

Comment: I have posted the solution.. can you please verify. appreciate your help.

Comment: You have the right idea; I've updated my answer to use `Element` and `Elements` instead of `Descendants`, per Robert's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This returns child elements as a string list not matter where it is.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName);


public List<string> FindChilds(string parentTag)
{
     return xmlDocument.Descendants().Where(x => x.Parent != null).Where(x => x.Parent.Name.ToString().Equals(parentTag)).Select(x => x.Name.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: very helpful in getting children at first depth.