# Getting to "bottom" of XmlDocument - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, iteration, xmlnode

I have two versions of XmlDocument

**Version 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topElement>

<childElement1>Value</childElement1>
<childElement2>Value</childElement2> 
...
</topElement>
```

**Version 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topElement>

<group1>
<childElement1>Value</childElement1>
<childElement2>Value</childElement2> 
</group1>

<group2>
<childElement1>Value</childElement1>
<childElement2>Value</childElement2> 
</group2>
</topElement>
```

In both occasions I need to get all the values for all childElements and add them to collection of a CustomObject. 
As far as I understand this could be done through iteration only.

So I get the top node, and go like this:

```
CustomObject getLow(XmlNode node, CustomObject customObject)
{
    foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (n.HasChildNodes == true)
        {
            getLow(n);
        }
        customObject.collection.Add(n.Name, n.InnerText);
    }
    return customObject;
}
```

No doubt it is wrong, please can somebody help me getting the correct result in both cases?

Comment: Ok, perhaps While loop isn't a great idea =) Shall I use if statement instead?

Comment: What is `getLow(XmlNode xmlNode)`

Comment: If `n` has child nodes you will never leave that `while` cycle.

Comment: @t3hn00b well, my bad, made a mistake there. Basically there method calls itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Xpath with your XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument("yourxml.xml");
foreach (XmlNode childElement in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//childElement"))
{
    customObject.collection.Add(childElement.Name, childElement.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping isn't the only way - another way would be to generate an object graph of custom classes with XML attributes and use the XML serilizer to convert the XML into an object graph.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx for details.

An alternative to that would be to use an XDocument and use linq to query the values you want straight out of the XDocument.

See [Using Linq and XDocument, can I get all the child elements under parent tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780379/using-linq-and-xdocument-can-i-get-all-the-child-elements-under-parent-tag)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use some xPath to get the nodes you are looking for.

Try something like

```
node.SelectNodes("//*[count(child::*)=0]")
```