# How to get XDocument child node

Tags: c#, xml

```html
<Users>
  <Account>
    <User>
      <Username>AdminUser</Username>
      <Password>pass123</Password>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <Account>Admin</Account>
      <Details>
   <Account>xyz</Account>
      </Details>
    </User>   
  </Account>
 <Account>
    <User>
      <Username>AdminUser</Username>
      <Password>pass123</Password>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <Account>Admin</Account>
      <Details>
   <Account>xyz</Account>
      </Details>
    </User>   
  </Account>
 <Account>
    <User>
      <Username>AdminUser</Username>
      <Password>pass123</Password>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <Account>Admin</Account>
      <Details>
   <Account>xyz</Account>
      </Details>
    </User>   
  </Account>
</Users>
```

After deserializing, I am getting XDocument as shown above. The "Account" node has child nodes with same name i.e. Account .How to get all the child nodes of "Users" node means I want to get three "Account" node under "Users" node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Linq and XDocument, can I get all the child elements under parent tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780379/using-linq-and-xdocument-can-i-get-all-the-child-elements-under-parent-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> accounts = doc.Root.Elements("Account");
```

In this example where `Account`s are the only direct children, you can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx)  :

```
IEnumerable<XElement> accounts = doc.Root.Elements();
```

You should use `XContainer.Elements("name")` to get direct children, or `XContainer.Descendants("name")` if you want to get all nested elements with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly try this it is use [Xpath Query](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) (it is tested and passed)

```
    var xml_string = "<Users>  <Account>    <User>      <Username>AdminUser</Username>      <Password>pass123</Password>      <Active>true</Active>      <Account>Admin</Account>      <Details>    <Account>xyz</Account>      </Details>    </User>     </Account> <Account>    <User>      <Username>AdminUser</Username>      <Password>pass123</Password>      <Active>true</Active>      <Account>Admin</Account>      <Details>      <Account>xyz</Account>      </Details>    </User>     </Account> <Account>    <User>      <Username>AdminUser</Username>      <Password>pass123</Password>      <Active>true</Active>      <Account>Admin</Account>      <Details>      <Account>xyz</Account>      </Details>    </User>     </Account></Users>";

    var xmlNodes = xml.SelectNodes("Users/Account/User");

    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}; Password: {1}; Active:{2}; Account: {3}; Details Account: {4}",
                                node["Username"].InnerText,
                                node["Password"].InnerText,
                                node["Active"].InnerText,
                                node["Account"].InnerText,
                                node["Details"].InnerText);
    }

  //result is

   // Username: AdminUser; Password: pass123; Active:true; Account: Admin; Details Account: xyz
   // Username: AdminUser; Password: pass123; Active:true; Account: Admin; Details Account: xyz
  // Username: AdminUser; Password: pass123; Active:true; Account: Admin; Details Account: xyz"
```

Gets 3 `User` nodes under `Account` node

**OR this:**  to gets the 3 `Account` nodes under `Users/Account`

```
            var xml = new XmlDocument();

            xml.LoadXml(xml_string);

            var xmlNodes = xml.SelectNodes("Users/Account/User/Account");

            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
            }

           //result is 

            //Admin
            //Admin
            //Admin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Root
                              .Element("Account")
                              .Elements("User"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}; Password: {1}; Active:{2}; Account: {3}; Details Account: {4}",
                              (string)element.Element("Username"),
                              (string)element.Element("Password"),
                              (string)element.Element("Active"),
                              (string)element.Element("Account"),
                              (string)element.Element("Details").Element("Account"));
        }
```